# Could not allocate requested partitions while instaling Scientific Linux

Tags: partition, software-installation, scientific-linux

I am installing Scientific Linux, and I must choose a drive to install it.

I have a deleted partition with the size of 150 GB.

[image]

When I select the deleted partition and try to create a partition

this happens:

[image]

> Could not allocate requested partitions: not enough free space on disks.

I cannot resolve the problem. Does anybody know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I formatted the deleted partition to ext4, then everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

You already have enough primary partitions which is why you get this message.

> You need a primary partition for linux and therefore you need to
>   delete the extended partition and make a primary one in its stead.

**References**

https://superuser.com/questions/702954/install-linux-error-could-not-allocate-requested-partitions-not-enough-free-s

**EDIT**

As per the OP when he reformatted the partition again as `ext4` the issue got resolved.

Comment: I wrote a comment on another post for this question but it has been deleted without notifying me.
I formatted the deleted partition to `ext4`, then everything worked.